# Hibernate SQLServer2017 Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc

Ok I am running the SQL native query below in my SpringBoot application with hibernate, please note this query is running fine in Sql Management Studio and returning some results. In my IDE I can use JDBC driver to connect to my SQL server 2017 and I can still run this query and return some results, now comes the strange part, when the same query is run inside the application I am getting the following error:

**Column 'ESB_TRANSACTION.time_in' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause**

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
        CASE WHEN (suc.transaction_time IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.transaction_time ELSE err.transaction_time END as transaction_time,
        CASE WHEN (suc.success_count IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.success_count ELSE 0 END as success_count,
        CASE WHEN (err.error_count IS NOT NULL) THEN err.error_count ELSE 0 END as error_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
          COUNT(et.status) error_count,
          DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / 1440) * 1440, 0) AS transaction_time
    FROM
          ESB_TRANSACTION et
    WHERE
          (et.status='ERROR')  AND (et.time_in BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-12 23:59:59')
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / 1440) * 1440, 0)
  ) err
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
          COUNT(et.status) success_count,
          DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / 1440) * 1440, 0) AS transaction_time
    FROM
          ESB_TRANSACTION et
    WHERE
          (et.status='SUCCESS')  AND (et.time_in BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-12 23:59:59')
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / 1440) * 1440, 0)
  ) suc ON err.transaction_time = suc.transaction_time
  ORDER BY transaction_time ASC
```

How exactly am i supposed to solve that?

Here is the relevant java code:

```
`public List execute(final String query, final DateRange selectedRange, final int minutes) {
    return (List) repository.getEntityManager()
            .createNativeQuery(query)
            .setParameter("startTime", selectedRange.getFrom())
            .setParameter("endTime", selectedRange.getTo())
            .setParameter("periodInterval", minutes   )
            .getResultList();
  }
```

The following simple java program to test the validity of the SQL is working fine:

```
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {
          String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\mssqlserver.sql")));
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(contents);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("transaction_time") + " =>" + rs.getInt("success_count") +" =>"+ rs.getInt("error_count"));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I actually get proper output, so what is wrong with my Spring Boot + Hibernate?

Comment: Are the JDBC drivers in IDE and Application same?

Comment: yes i am using the same driver

Comment: Could you show us the Java code? Just the relevant bit.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, i am adding it to the question

Comment: Could it be a Dialect issue?

Comment: I wrote a simply Java program to execute the SQL and it was OK, I got my output.

Comment: I tried the following dialects: (org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect and org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect) I even tried different versions of the driver and with no luck

Comment: Similar question found here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342601/hibernate-issue-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate/55649274 . It seems Hibernate is making noise for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (suc.transaction_time IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.transaction_time ELSE err.transaction_time END as transaction_time,
    CASE WHEN (suc.success_count IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.success_count ELSE 0 END as success_count,
    CASE WHEN (err.error_count IS NOT NULL) THEN err.error_count ELSE 0 END as error_count
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         COUNT(et.status) error_count, et.time_in AS transaction_time
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            eti.status,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, eti.time_in) / 1440) * 1440, 0) AS time_in
        FROM ESB_TRANSACTION eti
        WHERE
            (eti.status='ERROR')  AND (eti.time_in BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-12 23:59:59')
        ) et    
    GROUP BY et.time_in
    ) err
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
          COUNT(et.status) success_count, et.time_in AS transaction_time
    FROM
        (
        SELECT eti.status,
               DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, eti.time_in) / 1440) * 1440, 0) AS time_in
        FROM ESB_TRANSACTION eti
        WHERE
            (eti.status='SUCCESS')  AND (eti.time_in BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-12 23:59:59')
        ) et    
    GROUP BY et.time_in
    ) suc  ON err.transaction_time = suc.transaction_time
ORDER BY transaction_time ASC
```

**Note:** I don't have SQLServer, neither I gave it a go on any other DB. It should run as it is, nonetheless; if not, then probably it might require some minor syntax fix. However, result should be the one expected. In any case, it would, definitely, give you the idea. Hoping for good.

Comment: No this one doesn't work:  transaction_time is not a valid column name. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'transaction_time'.

Comment: O, actually this works in Postgresql, so I thought it might in SQLServer too. My bad.

Comment: Edited to provide an alternate query.

Comment: Btw, see my previous answer works in Postgresql. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659287/error-column-this-phitorsionangle-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-u

Comment: Selecting your reply as an answer but I figured out why this was giving me problems

Answer (score 1):

So i figured out why my query was failing: the actual query was like this:

```
SELECT
        CASE WHEN (suc.transaction_time IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.transaction_time ELSE err.transaction_time END as transaction_time,
        CASE WHEN (suc.success_count IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.success_count ELSE 0 END as success_count,
        CASE WHEN (err.error_count IS NOT NULL) THEN err.error_count ELSE 0 END as error_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
          COUNT(et.status) error_count,
          DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / :periodInterval) * :periodInterval, 0) AS transaction_time
    FROM
          ESB_TRANSACTION et
    WHERE
          (et.status='ERROR')  AND (et.time_in BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime)
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / :periodInterval) * :periodInterval, 0)
  ) err
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
          COUNT(et.status) success_count,
          DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / :periodInterval) * :periodInterval, 0) AS transaction_time
    FROM
          ESB_TRANSACTION et
    WHERE
          (et.status='SUCCESS')  AND (et.time_in BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime)
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / :periodInterval) * :periodInterval, 0)
  ) suc ON err.transaction_time = suc.transaction_time
  ORDER BY transaction_time ASC
```

the parameters: periodInterval, startTime and endTime where added during execution, this was the only difference between the SQL query during runtime and other the ones I was executing...so i decided to manipulate the sql query before running it to:

```
SELECT
        CASE WHEN (suc.transaction_time IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.transaction_time ELSE err.transaction_time END as transaction_time,
        CASE WHEN (suc.success_count IS NOT NULL) THEN suc.success_count ELSE 0 END as success_count,
        CASE WHEN (err.error_count IS NOT NULL) THEN err.error_count ELSE 0 END as error_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
          COUNT(et.status) error_count,
          DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / {periodInterval}) * :periodInterval, 0) AS transaction_time
    FROM
          ESB_TRANSACTION et
    WHERE
          (et.status='ERROR')  AND (et.time_in BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime)
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / {periodInterval}) * {periodInterval}, 0)
  ) err
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
          COUNT(et.status) success_count,
          DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / {periodInterval}) * {periodInterval}, 0) AS transaction_time
    FROM
          ESB_TRANSACTION et
    WHERE
          (et.status='SUCCESS')  AND (et.time_in BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime)
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, et.time_in) / {periodInterval}) * {periodInterval}, 0)
  ) suc ON err.transaction_time = suc.transaction_time
  ORDER BY transaction_time ASC
```

then I did a straight java string replace for {periodInterval} with the actual minutes , the resulting sql is with only :startTime and :endTime parameters I used it in hibernate and it was all good.

Comment: So, you never posted the original query, originally.